# removeDuplicates does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to extend Array prototype with the following functions:

```
Array.prototype.uniqueItems=function(){
    var ar=this,unique=[],max=ar.length;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < max;i++)
        if(unique.indexOf(ar[i] )==-1)
            unique.push(ar[i]);
    return unique;  
};
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates=function(){
    var self = this;
    self = this.uniqueItems();
    return self;
};
```

The first function is supposed to return an array without duplicates and the second to remove all duplicates from a given array.
Consider the following code:

```
var x=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4];
x.removeDuplicates();
console.log(x);
```

The output is :
    [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 ]
So the duplicates still remain.Any ideas why?Thanks In advance!!!!Also notice that I can not use `x= x.uniqueItems()` since it will work only for x.I want it to work for any given array.

Comment: `x = x.removeDuplicates()`. The method returns a new array rather than modifying the original. You'll have to store that somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thank you all for your answers .I found a simple solution to my problem by doing the following:

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates=function(){
    //First create a copy of the current array without duplicates
    var clear_array=this.uniqueItems();
    //Delete every item in the current array
    this.length=0;
    //Fill the current array with the elements of clear_array
    for(var i = 0;i<clear_array.length;i++)
        this[i] = clear_array[i];
    return this;
};
```

Also I did not use a Set since I want to be sure about backwards compatibility 
Hope this will be helpful to someone :)

Answer (score 1):

You might as well do it like this in ES6

```js
var x = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4],
    u = a => Array.from(new Set(a)),
    y = u(x);
console.log(y);
```

The new [Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in ES6 takes elements and keeps only one of each and discard the dupes. So it's in a way ideal to get unique items. A new set object is instantitated by the Set constructor and it will accept an array of items as an argument such as in `var s = new Set([1,1,2,1,4,3,6,7,4,5,6,9,8,1,2,3,4,7,0])` and the resulting `s` set will be composed of unique entries of 1,2,4,3,6,7,5,9,8 and 0 in the order of appearance. Set objects have generator properties and iterator functions which can be obtained from them. Hence `[...s]` (the ES6 spread operator) or `Array.from(s)` would result a proper unique items array automatically.

Comment: Would you mind to explain a little bit?It would be good for future visitors to know what this code does

Comment: @cssGEEK Yes you are right... i have just added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Also notice that I do not want this to happen only from x.If I have multiple arrays I want when I call the removeDuplicates() of each array to get rid of the dups.If you want check my own answer.

Comment: @cssGEEK You can throw in any array into the `u` function and provided it's items are primitive type like integers or strings, you get returned and array with unified items.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the `Array` to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and back allows for an arguably cleaner implementation:

```
Array.prototype.uniqueItems = function() {
    return new Array.from(new Set(this));
};

Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function() {
    this.from(new Set(this));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reassign to x.

```
var x=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4];
x = x.removeDuplicates();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: It would be the easiest way but no ;) .Check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

when you say

```
self = this.uniqueItems();
```

`self` is now pointing to a new array, not `this`

You need to either do

```
x = x.removeDuplicates();
```

or iterate `this` again in `removeDuplicates` to remove the other items.

For example

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates=function(){
    var self = this;
    var that = this;
    self = this.uniqueItems();
    //remove all items
    for(var counter = that.length ; counter >= 0; counter -- )
    {
      that.splice(counter,1);
    }
    //copy the individual items to this
    Object.keys(self).forEach(function(index){
      that[index] = self[index]
    });
    return self;
};
```

Comment: CAn you explain what you mean by saying " iterate this again in removeDuplicates to remove the other items"?